# What to do about this comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

[A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100820/difference-between-sync-and-await-in-netty#comment42705907_27100820) says:

> *I have no idea what netty is, but here's the difference with the help of Google: await - sync.*

What is the advised response (action) for this comment?  To me, it is mean-spirited, but I want to know what others think about it.

Comment: What about mentioning Google (and implying that said search engine may be able to solve your problem) is "mean-spirited"?

Answer (score 13):

I personally don't think that that comment is mean-spirited. It's an arguably bad question asking for a difference between two separate methods. This difference could easily be understood by reading through the documentation - which the comment links to - instead of posting a question.

*(Later on the author states that he read through them and didn't understand them, but the comment poster couldn't have known that. This is, by the way, a piece of information that should have been included in the question right from the start.)*

All in all it's a helpful comment linking to the official documentation for the two methods in question. I don't think the "with the help of google" necessarily means something is mean-spirited, it's just that the author didn't give any information about what he tried so far (like reading the documentation) and so on.

Comment: Side note: phrase like "I read the docs and don't get it" almost as bad for SO question as not mentioning any research at all. How one would know why OP did not understand something? Do they need some other book written for them? Personal guidance on reading? Maybe they don't even know basics of the language.